# Como colocar mais uma condição na cláusula on do join em uma query Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Essa query eu rodo no banco e está funcionando como deveria

```
select rci.markuppercentual from resellercatalogitem rci
join [Order] od on rci.ResellerCatalogId = od.ResellerCatalogId
join OrderItem oi on rci.ProductId = oi.ProductId and oi.OrderId = od.Id
where od.id = 4647 and rci.MarkupPercentual > 0
```

Na aplicação eu fiz isso

```
var qry = _resellerCatalogItemRepository.Table
                     .Join(_orderRepository.Table, rci => rci.ResellerCatalogId, od => od.ResellerCatalogId, (rci, od) => new { rci, od })
                     .Join(_orderItemRepository.Table, rci => rci.rci.ProductId, oit => oit.ProductId, (rci, oit) => new { rci, oit })
                     .Where(nod => nod.rci.od.Id == 4647 && nod.rci.rci.MarkupPercentual > 0)
                     .Select(s => new { s.rci.rci.MarkupPercentual}).ToList();
```

A diferença entre a query do banco e a da aplicação, é que na aplicação vem o registro 3 vezes. E ao observar na query do banco eu fiz isso

```
join OrderItem oi on rci.ProductId = oi.ProductId and oi.OrderId = od.Id
```

Acrescentei uma outra tabela e isso resolveu. Rodando a query que eu fiz, pego isso no Output do debug

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ResellerCatalogId] AS [ResellerCatalogId], 
    [Extent1].[MarkupPercentual] AS [MarkupPercentual]
    FROM   [dbo].[ResellerCatalogItem] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ResellerCatalogId] = [Extent2].[ResellerCatalogId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrderItem] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent3].[ProductId]
    WHERE (4647 = [Extent2].[Id]) AND ([Extent1].[MarkupPercentual] > cast(0 as decimal(18)))
```

Como eu adicono na query acima o equivalente a **and do join do banco** em uma query Linq/Lambda? No mesmo join mais uma condição

Comment: Ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Veja como criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) para utilizar na sua pergunta.